# How to solve this without rigorous calculation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$${{(99!)^{100}\cdot 99-(98!)^{100}\cdot 98}\over {(97!)^{100}\cdot 97}}=?$$

This is the question. This is not MCQ , neither an answer is given .

I have come to the following expression : $${{99^{101}-98}\over {97}}\cdot (98)^{100}$$

Can this be evaluated to be a number ? Would that be rational or integer ? Is there a short trick so I do not have to use calculator ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The integer part of the result has 399 digits, and you probably don't want to calculate them all by _any_ non-calculator method. What are you going to use the result for?

Comment: @HenningMakholm:       Just solving a pare that has this question  for one mark  with no answer or options.

Answer (score 1):

Using repeated squaring and $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \bmod p$ for the prime $p=97$, $(a,p)=1$, one can find that $99^{101}-98\equiv 31(\bmod 97)$, so that the result is not an integer.

Comment: can you elaborate? What is repeated squaring?

Comment: One doesn't even need repeated squaring, since by Fermat's little theorem $a^{101}\equiv a^{5}\pmod{97}$, so $$99^{101}-98 \equiv 2^{101}-1 \equiv 2^5-1 = 32 - 1 = 31 \pmod{97} $$

Comment: this much for 1 mark!

Comment: The "repeated squaring part" with $2^5\equiv 32 \bmod 97$ is trivial here, indeed. The $1$ mark is just for applying Fermat's little theorem, I think.